# How do you define a main page hierarchy in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

On this Doxygen generated help page http://api.fluffyunderware.com/curvy/index.html, there is a hierarchical documentation index for the main page and a table of contents.  How do I replicate this capability in my own documentation?

Here is a screenshot of the mentioned page:

[image]

Comment: Note, if I just create named files, they appear as entries in the Main Page, but I cannot see how to create a hierarchy below this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the example web page in your link, there are two main panes: on the left is an automatically-generated hierarchical *index* (what Doxygen calls a "**treeview**"), and on the right is a manually-generated *table of contents*. These are produced using different methods.

### Index

To create an automatically-generated hierarchical index, edit your Doxyfile, and make sure the following tag appears as shown:

```
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
```

The default value for the `GENERATE_TREEVIEW` tag is `NO`.

This will cause the index to appear in the left pane.

### Table of Contents

The Table of Contents in the right pane can be generated manually as follows.

Use nested **indented bulleted lists** in your markdown to manually create a multi-level hierarchy, and use `@ref` (or `\ref`) command tags to create hyperlinks.

Here is an excerpt from the doxygen documentation for my own project. I put this page in a document named "pages.dox", and added a reference to "pages.dox" to the `INPUT` tag in the Doxyfile.

```
/*! @page users_guide STFishFinder API User's Guide

@par Table of Contents

- @ref users_guide
    - @ref black_box
    - @ref api_overview
    - @ref stfishfinder_api
    - @ref wrappers
        - @ref ios_fishfinder_api
        - The Fish Finder API for Android   <!-- @ref android_fishfinder_api -->
        - The Fish Finder API for CLI       <!-- @ref windows_fishfinder_api -->
        - The Fish Finder API for Linux     <!-- @ref linux_fishfinder_api -->
        - @ref porting
    - @ref how_to
        - @ref how_to_connect
        - Flow of Information Overview      <!-- @ref flow_of_info -->
        - Advanced Gain Settings            <!-- @ref gain_how_to -->
        - How To Use the Depth Alarms       <!-- @ref depth_alarms_how_to -->
        - @ref simulator_how_to
        - Updating the Black Box Firmware   <!-- @ref firmware_update -->
        - @ref best_practices

*/
```

The page for the above excerpt is rendered by Doxygen as shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

Note that some of the entries in my table of contents are not links (e.g. *"The Fish Finder API for Android"*). This is because my API documentation is not finished yet, so I created "placeholders" for pages that haven't been written yet. I commented out the `@ref` links for these using HTML-style comment tags.

**See also**

- Online documentation for Doxygen's `@ref` command is at [this link](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdref).
- Documentation for Doxygen's
  **markdown** support is at [this link](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html).

Comment: "added a reference to "pages.dox" to the INPUT tag in the Doxyfile.".

How do you do that?

Comment: Add `[TOC]` seems can generate table of contents of current page.